# How to subtract 1 week from Easter Date in php

Tags: php

I have been trying to get php to subtract 1 week from Easter and the outputs are just downright bizarre.

This is what I currently have

```
<?php
    $year = date("Y");
    $easterdate = date('d-m-y',easter_date($year));
    $newdate = strtotime('-7 days', strtotime($easterdate)); 
?>
<body>
<?php echo $newdate;?> <br>
<?php echo $easterdate;?> <br>
</body>
```

The output I get is

newdate = 14-04-04
easterdate = 04-04-21

For some reason (which maybe very obvious that I can't see) is that when I try to calculate the minus 7 days, it subtracts the years and reformats it to Y-M-D.

I have reviewed the other forum questions about subtracting time and have tried various methods including the php.net site.

Comment: strtotime doesn't understand d-m-y dates (although you might have got lucky since date and month happen to be the same in this specific example). Try `$newdate = strtotime('-7 days', easter_date($year));` instead

Comment: Also strtotime returns a timestamp, not a formatted date, so it can't be outputting 14-04-04 as you claim - please review your question

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your help and pointing out my errors.

I don't know what happened, but it may have been a browser refresh problem.

My final code which works is

```
<?php
$year = date("Y");
$easterdate = date('d-m-y',easter_date($year));
$newdate = strtotime('-7 days', easter_date($year)); 
$newdate = date('d-m-y',$newdate);
?>
<body>
<?php echo $newdate;?> <br>
<?php echo $easterdate;?> <br>
```

The outputs are

newdate = 28-03-21

easterdate = 04-04-21

Answer (score 0):

Palm Sunday

```
$PalmSunday = strtotime('-1 week', easter_date());
echo date('M-d-y',$PalmSunday);
```

Beginning of Scrutinies

```
$FirstScrutiny = strtotime('-4 week', easter_date());
echo date('M-d-y',$FirstScrutiny);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one if i catch your problem,

```
echo date("d-m-y", strtotime(date("Y-m-d")." -7 days"));
```

Comment: That partially works. It does subtract the 7 days, but does not adjust for the month. so the output ends up being 28-04-21 rather than 28/03/21